# ActiveRecord without Rails: Can't run migrations

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have a legacy project which needs to be locked to ActiveRecord 5.2.  It does not run Rails.

I have database migrations at a custom path in the project tree.  I am trying to run the migrations but am hitting an error.  This is what the code I am using to run the migrations looks like:

```
def self.migrations_path
        File.expand_path('../schema', __FILE__)
      end

ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new(migrations_path).migrate(5.2)
```

but I receive the following error:

```
Failure/Error: ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new(migrations_path).migrate(5.2)

ArgumentError:
  wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 1..4)
```

What is the correct way to run migrations without Rails on ActiveRecord 5.2 (version is actually 5.2.8.1)?  Thanks for any help.

Edited to include full stack trace:

An error occurred while loading ./spec/spec_helper.rb.
Failure/Error: ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new(migrations_path).migrate(5.2)

```
ArgumentError:
  wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 1..4)
# /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.8.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:263:in `initialize'
# /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.8.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/schema_statements.rb:60:in `new'
# /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.8.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/schema_statements.rb:60:in `create_table_definition'
# /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.8.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:291:in `create_table'
# /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.8.1/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:29:in `create_table'
# /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.8.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1187:in `initialize'
# /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.8.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `new'
# /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.8.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `up'
# /usr/share/rvm/gems/rsongkickuby-3.0.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.8.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1017:in `migrate'
# ./lib/mycompany/oauth2/schema.rb:7:in `migrate'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:32:in `<top (required)>'
```

**I tried upgrading to ActiveRecord 6.0** and I now get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new(migrations_path).migrate(6.0)

ArgumentError:
  wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
# /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1028:in `initialize'
# ./lib/mycompany/oauth2/schema.rb:7:in `new'
# ./lib/mycompany/oauth2/schema.rb:7:in `migrate'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:32:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Please post a full stack trace. As of right now we do not have any idea where this error is occurring and nothing you have posted shows you passing 5 arguments.

Comment: Edited question to include full stack trace.  Thanks.

Comment: Rails `5.2.8.1` is not compatible with Ruby 3.0.1 and therefore I would expect the activerecord gem version `5.2.8.1` to not be compatible neither. According to this [table](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html) I suggest trying Ruby 2.5 instead or to upgrade `activerecord` to at least 6.1.x

Comment: What @spickermann posted is correct although you could bump this to `2.7`. Your issue is the same as many have been posting lately which is the [Separation of positional and keyword arguments in Ruby 3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/).

Comment: Thanks.  What would the correct way to run the migrations without Rails be on ActiveRecord 6.0?

Comment: I edited the question to include the error I get on ActiveRecord 6.0

Comment: As @spickermann pointed out you may have to move to atleast 6.1

Comment: [Rails 6.0 did not support Ruby 3.0](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html)! When you need to run it on Ruby 3.0 then you need at least Rails 6.1.

Comment: When running migrations in Rails 5 and later the migration version is set by the superclass of the migration. So you would use `MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]`. If its an older version then current ActiveRecord version it will be handled by a compatiblity adapter. You should not actually need to specify the version when calling the migrate method.  https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/migrations-are-versioned-in-rails-5